# Access Json Data

Tags: json, ajax

```
var myVariable
$.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        url:"connection.php",

        success:function(data){
            myVariable=data;
          }
    });


       $.each(myVariable, function(i,myVariable) {

        console.log(myVariable);
      });
```

this is how i get the data using ajax and result is like

```
Object {id: "2", lati: "6.03184", lon: "80.2158", description: "A"}
Object {id: "3", lati: "6.03594", lon: "80.2161", description: "B"}
Object {id: "4", lati: "5.97567", lon: "80.4295", description: "C"}
Object {id: "5", lati: "5.98916", lon: "80.3284", description: "D"}
Object {id: "6", lati: "6.1085", lon: "80.2237", description: "E"}
Object {id: "7", lati: "6.14061", lon: "80.0996", description: "F"}
Object {id: "8", lati: "6.95419", lon: "80.7902", description: "G"}
```

now i want to get only the 3 record 
Object {id: "4", lati: "5.97567", lon: "80.4295", description: "C"}
how can i do that i'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to access it by the key, you can't use "myVariable" as the value parameter in your `each()` function.

```
$.each(myVariable, function(i,mv) {
    if(myVariable[i].id === 4){
        var lat = myVariable[i].lati;
        var lon = myVariable[i].lon;
        var des = myVariable[i].description;
        console.log("the lat is "+lat", the lon is "+lon+" the description is "+des);
    }
});
```

Comment: i want like getting values from array like a[2] 
can i do like  that in here

Comment: what array there is no array ??

Comment: ohh i see. that will absolutely work, but not inside your `.each()` call because you are renaming the myVariable var.

Comment: so how can i do that any suggestion??.really appreciate your  help mate

Comment: you are not being clear i don't understand what you're asking. do it just like you did..`myVariable[3].id`

Comment: this is what is need 
    $.each(myVariable, function(i,myVariable) {
    strat_position=myVariable[i];
    end_position=myVariable[i+1];
});

Comment: see the edit. please hit the check mark if that helped.